# Maven looking for artifact in wrong location

Tags: maven

I have declared a dependency in one of my EJB module pom files for another module located within the project.

The project is structured as:

```
-- eS
|-- pom.xml
|-- eL
|   |-- pom.xml
|   |-- eLBO
|   |-- eLDAO
|   |-- eLBLImpl
|   |-- eLEJB
|   |   |-- pom.xml
|   |   `-- src
|   |       `-- main
|   |           |-- java
|   |           |   `-- eleague
|   |           |       `-- ejb
|   |           `-- resources
|   |               `-- META-INF
|   |                   |-- beans.xml
|   |                   |-- persistence.xml
|   |                   |-- (ejb-jar.xml)
|   |                   `-- (jboss-ejb3.xml)
```

The elBLImpl is packaged as a JAR, and I need to update the pom.xml file in my elEJB directory, to add a dependency on elBLIMpl. I tried this:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>elBLImpl</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Maven is saying that it cant find the module:

```
Failure to find eS.eL:elBLImpl:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://my-repo-location
```

Why is it looking for the elBLImpl in the repo, and not in the project itself?

This part is correct:

```
 eS.eL:elBLImpl
```

That is the module that elEJB depends on. But why is maven looking in an external repo, the module is part of the project itself. I must not understand maven too well, sorry. From within my EJB, I need to create instances of the classes inside the elBLImpl module.

Comment: you should provide that configuration you speak about if you expect to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess since we need more information, but have you installed the parent artifact for this one to find?

Also, you don't specify where Maven should look for a particular dependency. You simply define all your repository locations, and Maven looks in all of them, including your Maven local repo in `.m2`, to try to find them.

Comment: I see, but I'm trying to tell Maven that the EJB module needs a 'sibling' module. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you run `mvn install` from the parent pom?

Answer (score 1):

Maven don't care how do you forming your project structure. After building artifact it put it to local repository. And every project (nested or not) can get any other articact only from that repository(if none other repository is defined). So if you have trouble with getting some artifact, but you build it - please check if that artifact `<parent>`,  `<artifactId>` and `<version>` is same as you define as dependency.

Comment: How do I add to my local repository?

Comment: same error could not resolve dependency, but its looking for it in a repo that I defined in <repositories> at the root level of the project. The impl is part of the actual project.

Comment: as a note - folder names in project for maven is irrevalent to - only `<parent>`, `<artifactId>` and `<version>` is important. you can try to define these values directly, without using maven variables.

Comment: maven always use local repository - if none other option is defined

Comment: Ok, so I have to put the modules of the project that I'm creating in my local maven repo?

Comment: Maven does it themself during `mvn install` command. Maven manage dependensies themself. You need only define valid `<parent>`, `<artifactId>` and `<version>` in pom.xml of depended artifact, build it, and than use this values in artifact, that use this dependency in `<dependency>` tag.