# Maven: custom packaging of all child modules with specific contents

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

How to cutomize the maven run configurations in eclipse or editing the parent pom.xml which should perform creation of child module packages with only specific contents included to jar.

My Project Strucutre: Parent MavenProject(pom type) with six child modules(jar type)

currently i have added maven profile concept to child module as shown below:
I dont want to add the same thing across the child modules rather i want to add something in the parent pom.xml which pacakages all the child modules with specifc contents

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>client</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <classifier>client</classifier>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>com/xxx/yyy/zzz/*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Directory layout:

```
My Project Structure
    -- ParentProject
    |-- pom.xml
    |-- childmodule 1
    |   |-- src/main/java
    |   |    |-com.pages.abc ->package1
    |   |    |-com.pages.def ->package2
    |   |    |-com.tests.abc ->package3 
    |   |    |-com.tests-def ->package4      
    |   |-- src/main/resources
    |   |    |-resourde folder 
    |   |-- target folder
    |   |-- pom.xml
    |   |   
    |
    |--child modules 2 to 6  (similar structure as childmodule 1)
```

My actual reuirement is i need to skip all the test packages from the child module 1 to 5, except child module 6. I need to create the module jars excluding test packages for 1to5 modules. So added the profile "client" in parent pom.xml, am able to get the custom jars but am also getting default jar with all the packages. jars are present in target folder.

Comment: 1) Doesn't look like there's much point in the screenshot you've attached. 2) Please, illustrate your directory structure. 3) Please, illustrate the directory structure/files you would like to end up with.

Comment: Hi Carlspring, 1) am able to create custom jars with the specific contents for my chilkd mosules. 2) Now am in search of creating only custom jar on executing profile command like mvn package -Pclient. 3) currently am getting default jar also which i dont need

Comment: By the above I meant you showing the actual directory structures.

Comment: My directory structure : parent project is having 6 modules. Here my aim is to just include specific java packages for building custom jar creation for each module, which ve achieved already. But i need only custom jar to be present in the module target directory while packaging through profile which am still struggling..

Comment: Can you not put these explanations and the directory layouts in the question above? Can you not describe the layout like seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737121/maven-looking-for-artifact-in-wrong-location...? I mean -- if you don't describe your problem well enough, nobody'll help you.

Comment: I have updated the question with the project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have both default jar and jar with classifier because you added `execution` with specific configuration to `package` phase, but `maven-jar-plugin` already have default `execution` on `package` phase.

If you want only one jar after `mvn package` command you should adjust default configuration of `maven-jar-plugin`

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
        <id>client</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>client</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/xxx/yyy/zzz/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

or, as alternative, you can add `id` tag to execution with `default-jar` value, to allow only one execution of `maven-jar-plugin`

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>client</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-jar</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>client</classifier>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com/xxx/yyy/zzz/*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the code below to a parent pom and extend that parent from all the modules which should be applying it. The proposed trick will check if a pattern of sources exist, (or, alternatively, do not exist).

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>client</id>

        <file>
            <exists>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/xxx/yyy/zzz/*</exists>
            <!-- Or, alternatively, -->
            <missing>${basedir}/src/main/resources/foo.properties</missing>
            -->
        </file>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>client</classifier>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/com/xxx/yyy/zzz/**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: by implemeting the above in parent pom, two jars(default jar and client jar) are getting created for every child module. But includes or excludes is not happening. Both jars are of same size.

Comment: Include tag is working, but i need only custom jar to get created. am running parent pom.xml as mvn package -Pclient

Comment: I'm sorry... maybe you need to further explain what you have and what you'd like to do.

Comment: By adding the above profiles tag under parent pom.xml, currently two jars one default jar and the other default-client jar are getting created for every child module, my requirement is i need to create only default-client jar on executing package command for profile "client" (as mentioned above) like mvn package -Pclient. Also i need to mention particular contents to include or exclude for each child module before creating default-client jar. Pls let me know how to achieve the same.

Comment: I have updated the question with the project structure.. pls help.

Comment: am not able to find any new changes in the answer as per the comment.

Comment: The `<includes>` pattern is different. Give it a try.

Comment: am able to include the required contents to the custom jar, but when i package thru profile "client" its building default jar as well, i need to avoid that and also for few modules i need to avoid creating custom jar with the profile "client". Please help

Comment: Ok... Then maybe you should consider using the `maven-assembly-plugin` instead.